# Error: Unbound module Toploop, when trying to install merlin.

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocamlfind

I'm new to Ocaml. I'm trying to use merlin to get auto-completion in vim.

System: Arch Linux

Ocaml: version 4.07.0

```
`### stderr ###                                                                                                                            
 # File "frontend.ml", line 1823, characters 16-29:                                                                                          
 # Warning 3: deprecated: Stdlib.String.create                                                                                               
 # Use Bytes.create instead.                                                                                                                 
 # File "topfind.ml", line 55, characters 12-41:
 # Error: Unbound module Toploop
 # make[1]: *** [Makefile:165: topfind.cmo] Error 2
 # make: *** [Makefile:13: all] Error 2`
```

Here are the full [log](https://pastebin.com/3M1LkDv0) messages.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archlinux splits the compiler-libs package from the main ocaml package. You need to install ocaml-compiler-libs or use an opam-managed compiler.

Comment: Thank you @octachron. Installing an opam managed compiler and OCaml-compiler-libs solved the problem.